# run jupyter notebook file from a batch file that run another jupyter notebook file

Tags: python, batch-file, jupyter-notebook

my sistuation is that

I want to run a jupyter notebook file in a .bat file that call many jupyter notebook files to run as a sequence in a task scheduler.

The reason is that I don't want to schedule many jupyter notebook files in a task scheduler seperately. So i decide to have only one jupyter notebook that run% many jupyter notebook

Edited:
After i have read the comment i decide to give more precise information

- my main jupyter nb file name test.ipynb and i convert this file to test.py to create a .bat file
- in this test.ipynb i have many %run clean_transform.ipynb in a cell

### Code in my jupyter notebook cell

```
%run C:/Users/..../clean_transform.ipynb
```

when i open and manually run this cell in jupyter notebook, it works perfectly fine

however, after i create a .bat file by this jupyter notebook file

```
"C:\Users\...\python.exe" "C:\Users\....\test.py"
 @pause
```

it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\....\test.py", line 14, in <module>
get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', 'C:/Users/..../clean_transform.ipynb ')
NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined
Press any key to continue . . .
```

window pop up and show this error
can somebody help me on this
and any suggestion would be appreciate
thx

Comment: What's in test.py, where is `get_ipython` defined?

Comment: That `"C:\Users\...\python.exe" "C:\Users\....\test.py"` isn't how you'd run the notebook from the command line. Use [jupyter nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line) to execute on the command line or [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#command-line-conversion), with `jupytext  --execute <notebook.ipynb>`.

Comment: I don't know how you converted your notebook to `test.py`. If it's actually an `.ipy` file like it looks like it may be, you can use `ipython` to kick it if you change the extension to `.ipy`. However, if what you say is true, that you made one notebook to kick off the others, leave it as a notebook and use nbconvert or jupytext or papermill to run it. There's no need to convert further unless you really want to. The benefit of the notebook is that it will keep any feedback from during the run right there.

Comment: [Papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) is another popular command line program to execute notebooks and it adds the ability to parameterize the notebook. That's actually part of how Netflix does some of what you seem to be trying to do by running notebooks on schedules, see [Part 2: Scheduling Notebooks at Netflix](https://netflixtechblog.com/scheduling-notebooks-348e6c14cfd6).

Comment: @Wayne Hello there, I convert my test.ipynb by download as a test.py file. After I read your answer I will explore the nbconvert, jupytext, and papermill and get back to you with the result thx.

Comment: @AnonCoward Hello there, the test.py come from test.ipynb that i transform to .py file. I'm so new with get_ipython could you explain me more about this.

Comment: Okay, the conversion of the notebook to `.py` when saving the notebook from vanilla Jupyter isn't meant to convert to pure python that will work without additional work.  Or at least that is my experience. It is more that it is producing Python code format. The trick of changing the extension of the file the 'Save as' produces to `.ipy` and running it with IPython usually works because a lot of the tricks, like line magics (your example), come from IPython actually. If you have pure python in your notebook and then did the save as `.py` file from in your notebook then it would work.

Comment: Also, you may not want to be using `%run C:/Users/..../clean_transform.ipynb` in your unifying, shepherding notebook. That runs the notebook in the namespace of the notebook it is running in. For example if you have a cell with `print(2 + 2)` in the notebook being triggered, the result will show in the triggering notebook, not the one you thought you executed. However, you may have already set things up to account for that because you were using `%run` & not things like `jupyter nbconvert`. If you want the notebooks you are kicking off to have output use tools I mentioned to trigger them.

Comment: Getting back to using notebook vs script, in your case since you made the notebook upstream, I'd suggest using that with the tools I suggested to run it from the command line. If you didn't care at all about any feedback/output produced after your unifying, shepherding notebook is executed, you could just make a bash script that triggered running the other notebooks with those tools and kick that off with your chron job. Even then if you did care about some feedback as it runs, you could do some logging. The notebook just makes it easier because you get the logging and organizing built in.

Comment: @Wayne thx for the suggestion. papermill work very well for me

Comment: Good to hear. The ability to parameterize your notebooks using papermill makes it a really nice addition to your Jupyter toolbox.